# ZF2 autoloading custom modules with composer

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, autoloader

I'm trying to setup a ZF2 project (slightly different from the zf2skeleton) and I want to use composer to deal with all the autoloading, not only from the vendor ones (installed through composer) but also those modules I create.

For some reason, i can't get access to my Application module Index controller. I think its the autoloading that's not working... I just don't know what i might be doing wrong..

Thanks!

**Files and data below:**

This is my folder structure:

```
index.php
private
- modules
-- Aplication
--- src
----- Aplication
------- Controller
---------- IndexController.php
- vendor
-- zendframework
-- composer
-- autoload.php
- composer.json
- composer.phar
```

main.config.php

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'private/config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'cache_dir' => realpath(dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../data/cache'),
        'module_paths' => array(
            realpath(__DIR__ . '/../module'),
            realpath(__DIR__ . '/../vendor'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

index.php

```
include_once 'private/vendor/autoload.php';

$application = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'private/config/main.config.php');
return $application;
```

composer.json

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src"
        }
    }
}
```

Application config

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
);
```

IndexController

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        die("app ok");
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be too obvious, but you did run `php composer.phar update`? (if yes, i can't help, if no: do it!)

Comment: @Sam Yes, i did run update :) But no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from what I see, you don't run your application :

```
$application = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'private/config/main.config.php');
$application->run();
```

Another point is that, you don't have to use composer to load your modules. As your application config already include the `module` directory, the Module loading process will automatically scan the directory and use the loading strategy defined at the level your Module classes.

Comment: That was in fact the problem. But, why not use composer? What if i wanted to keep an "update method" but dont want to dump everything in the vendor folder? :| (that was my idea..)

Comment: your vendor folder is also marked as a module directory, See module_paths key on your config array